Sprinng Data JPA using OneToOne relationship (Hibernate)
I am using this simple example from baeldung (section 3.2). I have a Spring web application with two additional classes:
User.java:


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;
        //... 
    
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Address address;
    
        // ... getters and setters
    }

 
Address.java:


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "address")
    public class Address {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;
        //...
    
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
        private User user;
    
        //... getters and setters
    }


When I run the application I get the following error:
GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table users drop foreign key FKditu6lr4ek16tkxtdsne0gxib" via JDBC [Table 'sys.users' doesn't exist]
What is the problem with my code?
application.yml:


    spring:
      application:
        name: auction
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:9708/sys
        username: root
        password: pass
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      jpa:
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: create-drop
        database: mysql
        show-sql: true



Couple of observations, can you try updating the ddl-auto to update (or) create, and if you are using MySQL DB 'users' is an inbuilt table so probably try renaming the table 'users' to another name.

Changing ddl-auto to update made it work. Could you explain why is that?

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto -> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.
e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop. However, the schema should be owned by the DB and any DDLs should be incremental applied by Flyway or Liquibase.

Most likely users is in your database an already existing table, e.g., build-in.
Change your table name to something else.
In addition, do NOT use any CASCADE= on your owning (child) side of the mapping, that is a code smell. As you child is the owner of the relation ship, no CASCADE is necessary. CASCADEs may be placed (with care) on the non-owning (parent) side.

A beginner’s guide to JPA and Hibernate Cascade Types
What is the meaning of the CascadeType.ALL for a @ManyToOne JPA association

